# Launch screen on Xamarin.iOS not showing. A blue screen is shown instead

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm having some trouble on showing a launch screen only on my real iPad Mini device. When I run my app, a blue screen is shown instead.
I'm using an asset catalog to include the images. When I run on iPhone or on iPad 2 Simulators the launch screen shows perfectly!
Inside the Contents.json file in my asset catalog there are 4 images for iPad. They are:

**- Default-portrait.png (768x1004)**

**- Default-Portrait@2x.png (1536x2008)**

**- Default-Landscape.png (1004x768)**

**- Default-Landscape@2x.png (2008x1536)**

The Status Bar Style "Hide during application launch" option inside info.plist is unchecked.

I've followed the Managing Launch Screens with Asset Catalogs steps in Xamarin Launch Screen guide: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/#asset-catalogs

If someone knows what my mistakes are, please let me know! =]

PS: Sorry for the bad English!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like James Montemagno and Kevin Mullins answered in this post [Launch Screen](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55849/launch-screen), the new iOS devices need to use Storyboard instead of Assets Catalogs. I create a Storyboard and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for correct upper/lower case letters. The simulator is not case sensitive, e.g. it will gladly accept a  defAULT-PORtrait.png file. Your iOS device, on the other hand, *is* case sensitive.

More specifically, I noticed that your files are called :

- Default-**p**ortrait.png (768x1004)
- Default-**P**ortrait@2x.png (1536x2008)

Maybe it will help to dublecheck the spelling for all files, and asset catalogues to make sure they are consistent with your info.plist file.

Comment: Sorry @felix, the lower case was a typo when I wrote the question. The file name was correct in my project. I asked the same question in the Xamarin Forum: [Launch Screen](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55849/launch-screen). 
They told me to use Storyboard instead. And fortunately it worked out! Thank you for your attention!

Comment: @BernardoRocha Thanks for letting me know. I was not aware of that.